# Form not working with jquery post function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to do a simple user validation, however, when I try to use the post request function with the html form, the browser ignores jquery post request and instead sends a get request. A fresh set of eyes would help a lot!

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var user = $("#username");
    var pass = $("#password");
    var submit = $("#submit");

    $("#submit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("login.php", {
            username: user.val(),
            password: pass.val()
        }, function (data) {

            if (!data) {
                $("#login").append("Failed to reach server. Login Error.");
            }
            //$("div#login").hide();
            //$("div#welcome").css("display", "block"); else {
                loadpage();
            }

        }, "json");

        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the form in html, it's pretty simple:

```
<Div id="welcome"> Welcome </div>
<Div id="login">
    <br><br><h2>Welcome to This Site</h2>
    <br><br><br><form id="form"> Username:
    <input type = "text" name = "username"> <br> Password:
    <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password"> <br>
    <input type = "submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" class = "bluebutton"> 


</Div>
```

Just for the sake of eliminating any possible places for failure I hardcoded a username/password for the PHP here:

```
<?
if($username == "harry" && $password == "potter")
{
    $_SESSION["user"] = array();
    $array = array();
    $array["valid"] = "valid";
    echo(json_encode($array));
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form doesn't have a closing tag like `</form>` and also I didn't find any element in your form with id `submit`, so it's probably not triggering the function with following code

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){...});
```

instead it should be

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(event){...});
```

Also `return false;` is unnecessary because you have already used `event.preventDefault();`.

Your form should have a closing tag. i.e.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type = "text" name = "username"> <br> Password:
    <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password"> <br>
    <input type = "submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" class = "bluebutton">
</form>
```

Alternatively you can use

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rest of your code
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally spaced on the </form> tag and for some reason thought just having submit would make this work! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I see the problem is that in jquery you have

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
```

and in html you have

```
 <input type = "submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" class = "bluebutton">
```

if you put id="submit" in your input then it should work :)